# Could not resolve esbuild entry points

Tags: esbuild

The following esbuild CLI command works:
`esbuild server/**/* --platform=node --tsconfig=tsconfig.server.json --outdir=dist`

But if I create a config file and execute it with `node esbuild.js` command, it's not working. The error says that it could not resolve `server/**/*`.

**esbuild.js**

```js
esbuild.build({
    entryPoints: ['server/**/*'],
    platform: 'node',
    tsconfig: 'tsconfig.server.json',
    outdir: 'dist'
}).catch({
    process.exit(1);
})
```

I don't understand why it isn't working like the CLI command does.

Answer (score 6):

Your shell is the thing that expands the `server/**/*` syntax before the command-line arguments are passed to the `esbuild` command. Expanding globs is not a feature of esbuild itself. If you need to perform this expansion in JavaScript you'll need to use a library such as https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#globsyncpattern-options.

Answer (score 1):

esbuild entrypoints does not support glob patterns

example using external tool called [tiny-glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiny-glob) from the esbuild issue "[entryPoints does not support glob patterns #381](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/381)" (not mine)

```
const { build } = require("esbuild");
const glob = require("tiny-glob");

(async () => {
  let entryPoints = await glob("./src/*.ts");
  await build({
    entryPoints,
    /* ... */
  });
})();
```